# TabFolder changes selection itself after first click

Tags: java, tabs, swt

I have created a `TabFolder` with a few `TabItems`.

By default the first item is selected. But when I use the first mouseClick on the respective `Composite` the `TabFolder` is placed on to select any other item than the one that is already selected it will only select this item for short before it restores the selection of the first item.
However after having clicked the `TabFolder` once and hence made it gain the focus everything works as expected.

I checked with `SelectionListeners` that the reselection is not triggering a `SelectionEvent` and therefore I assume that this is some kind of internal behaviour.

Has anyone had this problem before or knows how to stop the `TabFolder` from reselecting the first element?

Here's how I am creating the `TabFolder`:

```
protected void createContent(Composite parent) {  
    InfoComposite comp = new InfoComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);  
    comp.setBackground(parent.getBackground());  
    comp.setForeground(parent.getForeground());  

    parent.setLayout(new FillLayout());  
    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());  

    folder = new TabFolder(comp, SWT.TOP);  

    // inherit color scheme  
    folder.setForeground(comp.getForeground());  
    folder.setBackground(comp.getBackground());  
}
```

EDIT:
I should mention that this `TabFolder` is part of a `AbstractInformationControl` in eclipse. I don't know whether this has something to do with my problem though.

EDIT2:
I now strongly suspect that this is a focus problem. I kept track of the focus and it turned out that the `TabItem` doesn't actually get focused on the first click. It's always the `StyledText` that is contained by the first `TabItem`... Only witht the second click the `TabFolder` actually gets the focus.
Is it possible that the `TabFolder` does not get focused when clicking one of the tabs?

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'll see what I can do...

Comment: So it turned out that I can't reproduce the problem as it seems not to be caused by the ``TabFolder`` but by focus problems instead... See my second edit do more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still don't know the the root of the problem I found out that it is most likely a focus problem.

However as the problem only occurs on the first mouseClick the workaround that did the job for me was to simulate this first mouseClick programmatically when the mouse enters the respective area of the `TabFolder`.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.MouseHover, new Listener() {

@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    // Check that this is the proper widget the action should be performed on
    event.widget.notifyListeners(SWT.MouseDown, new Event());
    event.widget.notifyListeners(SWT.MouseUp, new Event());
});
```

EDIT:
I now know that this problem is caused by the fact that the `TabFolder` is part of the `InformationControl` in eclipse, that opens a "different" window (an enriched one") when clicking on it. However my "enriched" version was the same window again and thus the "focus problem"